# Acrobat-like PopUp in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im recently working on some simple Imageviewer.

Now it came to my mind, it might be a nice feature, to do some context-sensitve actions like Zooming and rotating.

To implement these functions is not my problem, but the `ContextMenu` is.

I've decided to not use a `ContextMenu`-Element, instead im going to use a popup.

**Reasons for PopUp:**

- Less Styling
- Better Positioning
- IsOpen is Bindable (ContextMenu is NOT bindable on IsOpen against all Articles regarding this)

**Here comes the trouble:**

```
<Image x:Name="PART_ImgCurrent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Source="{Binding ElementName=PART_PreviewPanel, Path=SelectedItem.Source}">                                    
                                <Image.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"></RotateTransform>
                                </Image.LayoutTransform>
                                <Image.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ImgCurrent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:3" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>

                                </Image.Triggers>
                               </Image>
                            <Popup IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_ImgCurrent}" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="True" 
                                   IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PART_ImgCurrent, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   Placement="Right" HorizontalOffset="-42" VerticalOffset="2">
                                <StackPanel Opacity="0.5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Button Content="Ugly Button" Height="40" Width="40"></Button>
                                    <Button Content="Ugly Button" Height="40" Width="40"></Button>
                                    <Button Content="Ugly Button" Height="40" Width="40"></Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Popup>
```

As you can see, im binding `IsOpen` of `Popup` to `IsMouseOver` on Image which results in a funny Disco-BlinkenLights-Behavior when i try to click a button inside the `Popup`.

**What has this to do with the Title?**

AcrobatReader has this [image: this thingy]

This is almost exactly the behavior im looking for. How is this thing called?

Or had someone ever similar issues and could provide a solution?

Comment: So what you're seeing would actually be expected. Since as you pass your cursor to the Image, the PopUp IsOpen=True, once your cursor moves to the PopUp then Image no longer has IsMouseOver because PopUp just grabbed it in the Z-index, which throws IsOpen=False, as soon as it does that, Image gets it back and throws IsOpen=True and the behavior repeats to cause your blinking. Do you just want that when Mouse is Over image you get your menu and can interact and when Mouse leaves the image the menu goes away? Just making sure.

Comment: Well basically yes. I know, i could do this in Code-Behind without any problem, since its a `CustomControl` but as the Intellisense Tooltip stated (It sounds at least like this to me), `IsMouseOver` should let me do this. But it seems, PopUp is a never a child of Image in the VisualTree, so the only possible solution might be, to do this ll in Code-Behind.... I feared it

Comment: Hahaha no man don't over engineer it, you'll just make your life harder. You just need to pass the event and all you need is xaml. One sec I'll make an example. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, soon as I thought I had a second I got busy again. Anyway, here's one of several ways I can think of accomplishing your goal, give it a shot. I sort of assumed it may not be just images you want this for and if you threw the resource stuff in a dictionary and kept your naming consistent (or even better, just target the nested UIElement) you could use it all over the place. Notice the `Grid` is acting as what would be the `Image` in this example.

I generally make things open for future added interactions and stuff, so in this case I would probably just make the image source the background brush for `Grid` or place it as a child. That way if you decide to add other objects in there or say other effects and stuff you've got a good start point.

Anyway I digress, so try out the concept example below and see if it's what you're after. If not, like I said there's several other ways I can think of to accomplish your goal so just let me know. :)

```
<!-- HitTestVisibility Area -->
        <Grid x:Name="ImagePlaceholder"
              Height="500" Width="500" 
              Background="LightBlue">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="FakePopUp">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeave">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="FakePopUp">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeave}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>


            <!-- Overlay -->
            <Border Name="FakePopUp" Visibility="Collapsed"
                    Margin="0,0,0,25" Background="SlateGray" 
                    Height="50" CornerRadius="20" Padding="10" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="Eins Bier"/>
                    <Button Content="Zwei Bier" Margin="10,0"/>
                    <Button Content="Drei Bier"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </Border>

        </Grid>
```

I went with Storyboards attached to the parent instead of direct triggers with TargetName like I said, because I could think of a bunch of other instances features might want to be added that would make sense. Even something simple like adding a transition duration for a nice fade effect or maybe a translate y to slide it up while fading etc, etc, etc.

Anyway, hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: I like that idea with the `Grid` as wrapper. Works like a charm. Thanks man for that awesome inspiration :)

Comment: Good deal, glad you got a remedy. :)